# How to pass variables directly to compiler and access them inside code CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have compiled a couple of variables in my `CMakeLists.txt` that I want to access and display in a string inside my code. The way I am accessing them is by using some additional header files.

Is there a way to pass them directly to the compiler and still be able to use them inside my classes?

I think I will have to use some stringification somewhere in there.

CMakeLists.txt code:

```
add_definitions("-DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}")

configure_file(
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/version.h.in
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/version.h
    )

include_directories(
    src/
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated
)
```

version.h.in code:

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#define GIT_COMMIT_HASH "@GIT_COMMIT_HASH@"

#endif
```

automatically generated version.h code:

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#define GIT_COMMIT_HASH "a02cab8"

#endif
```

main.cpp code:

```
#include <version.h>

printf("GIT COMMIT HASH: %s", GIT_COMMIT_HASH);
```

For reference, I have followed [this tutorial](http://xit0.org/2013/04/cmake-use-git-branch-and-commit-details-in-project/)

Comment: So the code you've shown doesn't work for you? What is wrong with it? You did that - passed the macro as an argument to the compiler and configured a file - was that your intention? Can you clear up what exactly "pass variables directly to the compiler" and "access them inside code CMake" means? Access them _how_?

Comment: It works, I just want to find a way to do it without the additional header files.

Comment: ? So if you want to do it without an additional header, then remove it.

Comment: Command `add_definitions` actually *passes the variable directly to compiler*, so you don't need additional header. What is wrong when you use this command **without** the header?

Comment: `-DXXX=YYY` on the command line defines a macro named `XXX` that expands to `YYY`. `#define XXX ZZZ` in a source file defines a macro named `XXX` that expands to `ZZZ`. If you use both, they fight. Pick one.

Comment: how do I use the `add_definitions` variable inside main.cpp without the header files? Sorry for the uncertain questions, I am a beginner.